# Simple input function gives spyder an internal problem

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

This is the code I am trying to run.

```
x = int(input("Please enter and integer: "))

for n in range(2, x+1):
    for t in range(2, n):
        if n%t == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', t, '*', n/t)
            break
    else:
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

This is the error code I keep on getting. Worth noting that the code works if `x` has a predetermined variable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ausam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 138, in _dispatch
    handler(msg)
  File "C:\Users\ausam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 278, in _handle_input_request
    return super(DebuggingWidget, self)._handle_input_request(msg)
  File "C:\Users\ausam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 512, in _handle_input_request
    self._readline(msg['content']['prompt'], callback=callback, password=msg['content']['password'])
  File "C:\Users\ausam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\console_widget.py", line 2422, in _readline
    self._show_prompt(prompt, newline=False, separator=False)
TypeError: _show_prompt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'separator'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been reported on Github and is supposedly fixed. See https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17616

Instructions there are to upgrade to 5.3.0.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without upgrading (I am using an old version of basemap that is not compatible with the last versions of python so I don't want to upgrade..) ?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this because your version of spyder is not up-to-date. However, the issue is that if you update anaconda to its latest version it will still not work because the base anaconda repository does not include the latest version 5.3.1 of spyder. So you will create a new virtual environment and install the latest spyder from conda-forge using the code below in the command line or anaconda prompt:
`conda create -n NewSpyderEnv -c conda-forge spyder`
Then activate this environment using
`conda activate NewSpyderEnv`
Then start your spyder by just typing:
`spyder`